# Python check windows server version

Tags: python, windows

I need to log the current windows version in my python application for reporting purposes, but the built in functions I've found so far cant tell the difference between Windows client and server versions:

```
os.sys.getwindowsversion()
(6, 0, 6002, 2, 'Service Pack 2')
platform.release()
'Vista'
platform.win32_ver()
('Vista', '6.0.6002', 'SP2', 'Multiprocessor Free')
```

These functions return the same values on Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 (Since they share the same version number).

Is there any way to get the correct windows version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28VS.85%29.aspx) Win32 API and check the value of `wProductType` to differentiate.

Check out the [Python for Windows extension](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) package.

> VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER 0x0000002
>
> The system is a domain controller and
>   the operating system is Windows Server
>   2008, Windows Server 2003, or Windows
>   2000 Server.
>
> VER_NT_SERVER 0x0000003
>
> The operating system is Windows Server
>   2008, Windows Server 2003, or Windows
>   2000 Server.
>
> Note that a server that is also a
>   domain controller is reported as
>   VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONTROLLER, not
>   VER_NT_SERVER.
>
> VER_NT_WORKSTATION 0x0000001
>
> The operating system is Windows Vista,
>   Windows XP Professional, Windows XP
>   Home Edition, or Windows 2000
>   Professional.

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching it using WMI [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28VS.85%29.aspx) class (`ProductType` is `3` on server systems). [Scriptomatic](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=09dfc342-648b-4119-b7eb-783b0f7d1178&displaylang=en) can generate Python code for that.

Comment: ProductType is 2 on servers currently acting as a domain controller.

Comment: You can also use wmic os get OperatingSystemSKU. As long as you are using Windows Vista or newer (and it appears you are) that property should exist. A list of values for SKU appears here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28VS.85%29.aspx