# Identify Windows Editions

Tags: python, windows, windowsversion

I am writing a function which prints out detailed Windows Version informations, the output may be a tuple like this:

```
('32bit', 'XP', 'Professional', 'SP3', 'English')
```

It will be supporting Windows XP and above. And I'm stuck with getting the Windows edition, e.g., "Professional", "Home Basic", etc.

platform.win32_ver() or sys.getwindowsversion() doesn't do it for me.

[win32api.GetVersionEx(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834446/python-check-windows-server-version) almost hits, but looks like it doesn't tell me enough information.

Then I saw [GetProductInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724358(v=VS.85).aspx), but looks like it's not implemented in pywin32.

Any hints?

Comment: Seems not pythonic to try to make a platform dependant python code... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) to access any WinAPI function. `GetProductInfo()` is in `windll.kernel32.GetProductInfo`.

I'd found a [Python version](http://www.eventghost.org/svn/branches/bitmonster/plugin-install/eg/WinApi/SystemInformation.py) (GPL licensed, but you can see usage of the functions there) of the [MSDN "Getting the System Version" example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724429(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Great! How did you find that python version?

Comment: By searching for "windll.kernel32.GetProductInfo" on Google.

Answer (score 2):

If ctypes doesn't work (due to 32 vs 64 bits?), this hack should:

```py
def get_Windows_name():
    import subprocess, re
    o = subprocess.Popen('systeminfo', stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    try: o = str(o, "latin-1")  # Python 3+
    except: pass  
    return re.search("OS Name:\s*(.*)", o).group(1).strip()

print(get_Windows_name())
```

Or just read the registry:

```
try: import winreg
except: import _winreg as winreg
with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion") as key:
    print(winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "EditionID")[0])
```

Or use this:

```
from win32com.client import GetObject
wim = GetObject('winmgmts:')
print([o.Caption for o in wim.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")][0])
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried a few of the solutions above, but I was looking for something that gave me "Windows XP" or "Windows 7".  There are a few more methods in [platform](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html) that expose even more information.

```
import platform
print platform.system(),platform.release()
```